# How to generate multiple records based on column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have records like below. I would like to convert a single record into two records with values `EXTERNAL` and `INTERNAL` each if the 3rd attribute is `All`.

Input dataset:

```
Surender,cts,INTERNAL
Raja,cts,EXTERNAL
Ajay,tcs,All
```

Expected output:

```
Surender,cts,INTERNAL
Raja,cts,EXTERNAL
Ajay,tcs,INTERNAL
Ajay,tcs,EXTERNAL
```

**My Spark Code :**

```
case class Customer(name:String,organisation:String,campaign_type:String)

val custRDD = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/input_files/customer.txt")

val mapRDD = custRDD.map(record => record.split(","))
    .map(arr => (arr(0),arr(1),arr(2))
    .map(tuple => {
      val name            = tuple._1.trim
      val organisation    = tuple._2.trim
      val campaign_type   = tuple._3.trim.toUpperCase
      Customer(name, organisation, campaign_type)
    })

mapRDD.toDF().registerTempTable("customer_processed")

sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM customer_processed").show
```

Could Someone help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's Scala...

If you want to write a more idiomatic Scala code (and perhaps trading some performance due to lack of optimizations to have a more idiomatic code), you can use [flatMap](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@flatMap[U](func:T=%3ETraversableOnce[U])(implicitevidence$8:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[U]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U]) operator (removed the implicit parameter):

> **flatMap[U](func: (T) ⇒ TraversableOnce[U]): Dataset[U]** Returns a new Dataset by first applying a function to all elements of this Dataset, and then flattening the results.

NOTE: `flatMap` is equivalent to `explode` function, but you don't have to register a UDF (as in the other answer).

A solution could be as follows:

```
// I don't care about the names of the columns since we use Scala
// as you did when you tried to write the code
scala> input.show
+--------+---+--------+
|     _c0|_c1|     _c2|
+--------+---+--------+
|Surender|cts|INTERNAL|
|    Raja|cts|EXTERNAL|
|    Ajay|tcs|     All|
+--------+---+--------+

val result = input.
  as[(String, String, String)].
  flatMap { case r @ (name, org, campaign) => 
    if ("all".equalsIgnoreCase(campaign)) {
      Seq("INTERNAL", "EXTERNAL").map { cname =>
        (name, org, cname)
      }
    } else Seq(r)
  }
scala> result.show
+--------+---+--------+
|      _1| _2|      _3|
+--------+---+--------+
|Surender|cts|INTERNAL|
|    Raja|cts|EXTERNAL|
|    Ajay|tcs|INTERNAL|
|    Ajay|tcs|EXTERNAL|
+--------+---+--------+
```

---

Comparing performance of the two queries, i.e. `flatMap`-based vs `explode`-based queries, I think `explode`-based may be slightly faster and optimized better as some code is under Spark's control (using logical operators before they get mapped to physical couterparts). In `flatMap` the entire optimization is your responsibility as a Scala developer.

The below red-bounded area corresponds to `flatMap`-based code and the warning sign are very cost expensive `DeserializeToObject` and `SerializeFromObject` operators.

[image]

What's interesting is the number of Spark jobs per query and their durations. It appears that `explode`-based query takes 2 Spark jobs and 200 ms while `flatMap`-based take only 1 Spark job and 43 ms.

[image]

That surprises me a lot and suggests that `flatMap`-based query *could* be faster (!)

Comment: As much I like the way you have put the answer, I don't agree with your benchmark method. You are comparing flatMap vs explode on 3 rows as input and concluding that flatMap is faster, and here is where I don't agree.

Comment: Correct. I agree with you that the size of the dataset might have led to a false conclusion, but...until you've proved I'm wrong, that's the only benchmark we've got. "Beliefs vs results" - spare myself picking your favourite.

Comment: Do you seriously believe that benchmarking `Spark` code on 3 row datasets will tell you anything about performance?

Comment: Give me a better test dataset and I'll stand corrected. Prove I'm wrong for mutual interest and mastering Spark. I'd rather put my beliefs aside.

Answer (score 3):

You can use and `udf` to transform the campaign_type column containing a `Seq` of strings  to map it to the campaigns type and then `explode` :

```
val campaignType_ : (String => Seq[String]) = {
  case s if s == "ALL" => Seq("EXTERNAL", "INTERNAL")
  case s => Seq(s)
}

val campaignType = udf(campaignType_)

val df = Seq(("Surender", "cts", "INTERNAL"),
  ("Raja", "cts", "EXTERNAL"),
  ("Ajay", "tcs", "ALL"))
  .toDF("name", "organisation", "campaign_type")

val step1 = df.withColumn("campaign_type", campaignType($"campaign_type"))
step1.show
// +--------+------------+--------------------+
// |    name|organisation|       campaign_type|
// +--------+------------+--------------------+
// |Surender|         cts|          [INTERNAL]|
// |    Raja|         cts|          [EXTERNAL]|
// |    Ajay|         tcs|[EXTERNAL, INTERNAL]|
// +--------+------------+--------------------+

val step2 = step1.select($"name", $"organisation", explode($"campaign_type"))
step2.show
// +--------+------------+--------+
// |    name|organisation|     col|
// +--------+------------+--------+
// |Surender|         cts|INTERNAL|
// |    Raja|         cts|EXTERNAL|
// |    Ajay|         tcs|EXTERNAL|
// |    Ajay|         tcs|INTERNAL|
// +--------+------------+--------+
```

**EDIT:**

You don't actually need a udf, you can use a when().otherwise predicate instead on `step1` as followed :

```
val step1 = df.withColumn("campaign_type", 
when(col("campaign_type") === "ALL", array("EXTERNAL", "INTERNAL")).otherwise(array(col("campaign_type")))
```